# how to update a specific row that has the same values as the other row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having a hard time figuring this one out. I have this database that will get bigger sooner or later and it looks like this.

```
est_id |mat_id | est_qty | qty_rec
   2   |  29   |    50   |    0
   3   |  29   |    70   |    0
   8   |  29   |   100   |    0
```

Now, what I want to accomplish is to update a single row until est_qty and qty_rec are equal then move to the other one after. I started a code but its not working.

```
    foreach($mat_id as $mat_id_key => $mat){
    while($rec_qty > 0){
        $remBal = $est_qty[$mat_id_key] - $qty_rec[$mat_id_key];
        if(($remBal - $rec_qty) >= 0){
            mysql_query('UPDATE `estimates` SET `qty_rec` = `qty_rec` + '.$rec_qty.' WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.$mat[$mat_id_key].'"');
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, each row will go in to loop, until its going to satisfy the condition which is the difference between est_qty and `$rec_qty` is a greater than or equal to zero it will update that row.

For instance, the user input 30 as the `$rec_qty`, the database will now look like:

```
est_id |mat_id | est_qty | qty_rec
   2   |  29   |    50   |   30
   3   |  29   |    70   |    0
   8   |  29   |   100   |    0
```

When the user inputs the second time around, for instance 40 as `$rec_qty`, the database will now look like:

```
est_id |mat_id | est_qty | qty_rec
   2   |  29   |    50   |   50
   3   |  29   |    70   |   20
   8   |  29   |   100   |    0
```

Comment: How do you know the order in which to apply the qty_rec?  Smallest to largest est_qty?  Also, what is the primary key here?  `proj_id`?  You might show all the columns.  Does this involve SQL Server at all or just MySql?

Comment: I'm personally not understanding the application itself. So user inputs qty_rec into a form? So qty_rec starts off as 0. And est_qty are values predetermined by you? What if est_qty = 60 and user inputs qty_rec = 70? I'm just very confused.

Comment: @TimLehner, please the updated question.est_id is the primary key.thank you. :]

Comment: @bowlerae, yes, the user inputs into a form. And the est_qty are predertermined by me. If the user inputs higher than est_qty the 10 will go to the next row's rec_qty sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a set-based single query to do this, though it uses a [triangular-join](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/61539/):

```
update est as e
    join (
        select *
            , case when needed - room_below > room then room else needed - room_below end as to_add
        from (
            select *
                , est_qty - qty_rec as room
                , (select coalesce(sum(est_qty - qty_rec), 0) from est where mat_id = a.mat_id and est_id < a.est_id) as room_below
                , 30 as needed -- Variable?
            from est as a
        ) as b
    ) as c on e.est_id = c.est_id
set e.qty_rec = e.qty_rec + c.to_add    
where e.mat_id = 29 -- Variable?
    and c.to_add > 0;
```

It should be noted that this has no logic to deal with an overflow condition, where you're trying to insert a larger number than can be fit in the existing records (you'd possibly have to insert a new record to hold the remainder).

There is a SqlFiddle demo [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4ff9/2).

Comment: thank you very much sir.Your help is very much appreciated. :]

Answer (score 0):

Because your table does not have a unique id, your UPDATE will update *all* rows that match proj_id and mat_id. Thus, if you start out with:

```
mat_id | est_qty | qty_rec
  29   |    50   |   30
  29   |    70   |    0
  29   |   100   |    0
```

and add 40, you will end up with:

```
mat_id | est_qty | qty_rec
  29   |    50   |   70
  29   |    70   |   70
  29   |   100   |   70
```

or even:

```
mat_id | est_qty | qty_rec
  29   |    50   |   40
  29   |    70   |   40
  29   |   100   |   40
```

...depending on which row was found first.

Add a primary key to your table, then update the record based on this ID.

Comment: I forgot to include it earlier. Sorry for that. I edited the tables and added the primary keys.

Comment: Okay, then use the est_id in your UPDATE statement and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the loop. These two queries should suffice:

```
mysql_query("set @remain := $rec_qty");
mysql_query(
  "update estimates
     set qty_rec = @remain,
         qty_rec = qty_rec - (@remain := if( qty_rec > est_qty, qty_rec - est_qty, 0)
     where mat_id = $matId
   order by est_id"
);
```

$matId is the mat_id you want to update.